# TableView scrolling stutters after adding images from remote URL

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uitableview

I am building an iOS app that adds XML items to a TableView (among other things, of course). I would like to display the article's thumbnail in the TableView cell or a default placeholder if the article's thumbnail field is empty.

The code below adds the thumbnail from the article but then causes scrolling to stutter quite a bit. If I only use the placeholder image for each cell, everything is fine. I am guessing I am probably not using the most ideal method to add the thumbnail image, not sure if this is causing the problem.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"idCellNewsTitle"];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"idCellNewsTitle"];
    }
    NSDictionary *dict = [self.arrNewsData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"holder-small.jpg"];
    cell.textLabel.text = [dict objectForKey:@"title"];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [dict objectForKey:@"pubDate"];
    if ([dict objectForKey:@"thumbnail"] != nil) {
        NSData *imgData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString: [dict objectForKey:@"thumbnail"]]];
        if (imgData) {
            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imgData];
            if (image) {
                cell.imageView.image = image;
            }
        }
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Coding in the latest XCode, testing in simulator and on a newer iPod - results are the same with both. No warnings or errors during the running of the app, CPU spikes at 1% when scrolling and memory stays around 16 MB.

**UPDATE - Video**
Here is a video demonstrating this issue for any future noobs to compare with -
First example is with a placeholder, second is without.
[Video on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=img7_IYduT0&feature=youtu.be)

Comment: dont do this "dataWithContentsOfURL" on main thread , use a background thread for this task

Comment: I'm just learning iOS programming - can you elaborate a bit on this or perhaps post an answer with some example code? I'd really appreciate it. Thanks for your feedback :)

Comment: You should also cache the images so you aren't downloading the same image every time the UITableViewCell becomes visible.

Comment: So, basically every time a cell comes into view it is downloading the image over and over again?

Comment: Exactly. Use an NSMutableArray or NSCache and add the image to it. Then, check if the image exists in the array or cache before attempting to download it again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace your code in cellForRowAtIndexPath:

after this line `if ([dict objectForKey:@"thumbnail"] != nil)`

That way you load each image in the background and as soon as its loaded the corresponding cell is updated on the mainThread.

```
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^(void) {
        NSData *imgData =  NSData *imgData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString: [dict objectForKey:@"thumbnail"]]];
        if (imgData) {
           UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imgData];

           dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {
             UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imgData];
                      if (image) {
                           cell.imageView.image = image;
             }
        });
    });
```

[LazyTableImages Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html)

Comment: Okay, after cleaning up the code a bit I have this working - it's pretty sweet except for one thing. Scrolling is zippy now but as I scroll I see my placeholder flicker in and out. Should I maybe just omit the placeholder image and just have the `cell.imageView` left out unless there is a thumbnail?

Comment: i knew that , you are going to complain this . the solution for this problem is to cache the image. i will suggest you to use anyone of these solution . [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) "i always prefer this" [AsyncImageView](https://github.com/nicklockwood/AsyncImageView)

Comment: Psychic! Thanks for the tip. +1 and selected answer for you :)

Answer (score 0):

Fetch images using GCD

```
// Fetch using GCD
  dispatch_queue_t downloadThumbnailQueue = dispatch_queue_create("Get Photo Thumbnail", NULL);
  dispatch_async(downloadThumbnailQueue, ^{
    UIImage *image = [self getTopPlacePhotoThumbnail:photo];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        UITableViewCell *cellToUpdate = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]; // create a copy of the cell to avoid keeping a strong pointer to "cell" since that one may have been reused by the time the block is ready to update it. 
        if (cellToUpdate != nil) {
            [cellToUpdate.imageView setImage:image];
            [cellToUpdate setNeedsLayout];
        }
    });
  });
```

Comment: Would this go after `if ([dict objectForKey:@"thumbnail"] != nil) {`?'